# How to use aws cli with dynamodb to query for index whose name contains ':'?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Reading the documentation I can see that key filter expression should look like:

`partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval`

however, the values of my GSI contain `:` in themselves. So using this:

`aws dynamodb query --table-name my_table --index-name mark_id_index --select ALL_ATTRIBUTES --key-condition-expression mark_id=:bit:BT-EU:dev`

causes the following error:

`An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: ":BT", near: ":bit:BT-"`

They also mention using `#` if the word is reserved, but I think in my case it is the character that is reserved. I have tried to google around `#` variables but cannot find anything.

Comment: Use the expression-attribute-values option.